# Using ternary operator in linq to simulate CASE based concatenation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, concatenation

I'm trying to build a query where I have to concatenate 2 specific fields together depending on the value of a 3rd one:

```
var query = (from ds in Datacenter.datastatus
                     where ds.visible == "y" 
                     select new 
                     { 
                         ds.Priority, 
                         ds.country.Country_Name, 
                         ds.DSFromDate,
                         ds.DSToDate,
                         receptiontype = ds.Datatype == "QH" ? Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_IdQH).Select(x => x.Name) + " - " + ds.country.ReceptionCommentQH :
                         ds.Datatype != "QH" ? Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_Id).Select(x => x.Name) + " - " + ds.country.ReceptionComment :
                         ""                       
                     }).ToList();
```

In my case I will have 2 different concatenations depending on if "datatype" field value equals "QH" or not.

When running the code I run into an exception that I don't really understand:
"DBArithmeticExpression agruments must have a numeric common type"

I supposed the error might come from the way I'm doing the string concatenation and therefore tried the following code:

```
 receptiontype = ds.Datatype == "QH" ? String.Concat(Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_IdQH).Select(x => x.Name), " - ", ds.country.ReceptionCommentQH) :
                         ds.Datatype != "QH" ?  String.Concat(Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_Id).Select(x => x.Name), " - ", ds.country.ReceptionComment):
                         ""
```

But since I'm using the Entity framework, I'm getting the classic "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat" since it doesn't seem able to convert the concatenation into SQL.

Any hint on how to perform my concatenation ?

Comment: Your trying to concatenate the result of a `Where()` with a string. I am not sure this would work either but you would certainly need to do a `Single()` or `First()` instead of a `Where()` to ensure you get exactly one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Datacenter.reception_type.Where(x => x.Id_reception_type == ds.country.ReceptionType_IdQH).Select(x => x.Name)` is a collection. And to that you're trying to concatenate a string, which really is nonsensical, so the first approach fails.

If the collection is supposed to have just one item, use `.First()` or `.Single()` and then concatenate with the `+` operator.

If the collection is supposed to have multiple items that you need to concatenate... then I don't know.